# How do I share a SkyDrive Pro file using the REST API?

Tags: onedrive-for-business

I'm writing an Windows console application to migrate Google Drive files for 130 Google Apps accounts to SkyDrive Pro. I have been using a mixture of the REST API (where I can find documentation) and SOAP (where I've needed to packet sniff other applications to find out how to do things that I can't find in the REST API documentation).

I've been able to upload files to all users SkyDrive Pro and set the author, create date time and modified date time but can't find any documentation on sharing those files.

How do I share a SkyDrive Pro file using the REST API (or SOAP)?

Comment: I agree the REST API Documentation for SP2013 is very bare bones at the moment. A lot of info appears to be trial and error (e.g. webinfos/add to create subsites).